# Avoid entering a for loop when the start is larger than the end

Tags: r, for-loop

The function receives an integer parameter c that takes values from 1 to some positive n, and I want that the loop doesn't iterate when c=1 i.e when start value of the for loop is larger than the end value.

Approach shown below doesn't work:

```
repeted_f<-function(C_matrix, g, n, c, aux) {
  for(c_i in (2:c)) {
     #some small code here
  }
  return (F);
}
```

If c=1 c_i will iterate 2 and 1 rather than not iterate at all.

I have also tried replacing (2:c) by seq(2,c, by=1) hoping that this would give me an empty set, but I get an error:

```
Error in seq.default(2, c, by = 1) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

I know I can just check if (2>=c) before getting into the loop, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

R will always generate a range, even in negative direction. Therefore you will have to do what you mentioned, add if condition before looping.